# Open all links in new tabs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, anchor, target, attr

I have some links that are placed in my page dynamically via JSON and have no way to directly edit them. I want to force all links to open in new tabs, ala `target="_blank"`

Thought this would work.. but sadly it isn't. Any ideas?

```
 $('a').attr("target","_blank");
```

Here's a jsFiddle with the dynamic code:
http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/mrgta/7/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do this (which lets the users browser decide whether to open a new window or tab)

```
$('a').live('click', function() {
  window.open($(this).attr('href'));
  return false;
});
```

For jQuery 1.7+:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
  window.open($(this).attr('href'));
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted? It should work as advertised. On a side note, I do like setting the `target` attribute to `_blank`, as was suggested in other answers, because I am old school and it works well. But this particular solution---if one even cares about such things---is actually the one that should be recommended if one cares about validating (since `target` is a deprecated attribute).

Comment: P.S., please see my separate answer on this page, which endorses this same answer for another reason: timing.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem might be one of timing.

Keep in mind, when you call something like `$('a').attr(...whatever...)`, that it will take effect **instantly**, upon any and all *existing* elements on the page. So, ... if your `tweet` plugin is asynchronous and takes more than 0 milliseconds to perform, it looks like your code is trying to change attributes on links that *don't even exist on the page yet*.

That is, you might be (A) calling the `tweet` plugin, (B) changing all links on the page, and then (C) the tweet plugin completes and injects a bunch of new links on the page that got missed earlier.

So, what you could try, is see if the `tweet` plugin you are using has some kind of "all-done" or other completion callback, that you could then use to change around the link tags. Or, like another answer suggested, which I also endorse, is to not just try and change the link tags, but to instead listen (live) upon any link clicks on the page, and intercept them at that point in time. This way, you don't need to worry about the timing/completion of the tweet plugin, since you could use event delegation (`live`) which works at any point in time. See the answer from Petah for a great example of how to do this.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<a href="http://www.google.com">test</a>
<br />
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">test2</a>

<script>
    $('a').attr('target', '_blank');
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you replace `'new'` with `'_blank'` does it still work for you?  Just asking.  If it does, maybe the OP has other issues.  If it doesn't, I'd like to know why.

Comment: @Dave Maple - No dice. Loaded up a jsFiddle to demonstrate. Posted in the question

Comment: @Dave Maple - forgot to mention that your code works on existing links, but not links loaded in via JSON.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, she definitely has another issue.

Comment: @technopeasant: can't you just call the same code in a callback after the json is parsed and loaded into the dom? can you update with a snippet of how you're loading the links via json?

Comment: @Dave - it's in the jsFiddle. Using a Twitter plug in.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('a').attr({ target: "_blank" });
```

Also, try "_new" instead of blank. If that doesn't work, why not post the generated html or your entire javascript code?

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because the `<a>` is not yet part of your page when `$('a').attr("target","_blank");` is fired.

Comment: @technopeasant, I am not sure.