# Twitter and Facebook Feed without any outgoing links

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook, twitter

I have a client that is wanting to embed their social media timelines within their website, but does not want them to contain any outgoing links that would take the visitor away from the website. I am wondering if this is possible. I have tried to look through the API's without any luck.

I have also tried just disabling the links within the containers using both CSS and Jquery (non-functional).

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MLNHS/)

These are the two methods i've tried:

CSS:

```
pointer-events: none;
cursor: default;
```

Jquery:

```
$("#twitter-feed a").css({"color":"#888888", cursor: "default"}).click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
});
```

So far i've only been testing on the Twitter feed. I can get the CSS to disable the links, but it also keeps the widget from being able to scroll.

Having said all that, i've been trying this with a Twitter widget created through twitter.

Comment: Doesn't the JQuery do what you are after? Feels like it should unless every tweet is an anchor link.

Comment: As an alternative, could you force the links to open in a new tab/page? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287353/open-all-links-in-new-tabs-with-jquery

Comment: Yes they already open in a new tab, which is fine for me, but my client wants the links to completely not work. They don't want any chance of driving traffic away from the site.

Comment: hmm.. it depends on the structure of the tweet then. Do you have that and could you edit your post to provide that?

Comment: also, at this point i have not been able to get that jquery to work. It doesn't seem to even be responding. I have called the jquery library in the header.

Comment: JSfiddle then...we need code to work with.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MLNHS/

Comment: Ahh...it's injecting an `<iframe>`. That will cause issues.