# Trying to make anchors open in another window using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a section of my webpage (#skills) where I want anchors to open in a new tab when clicked. I allready did this on some other pages, by just targeting every link with a specific selector, but now I want to target all links, except for the ones inside my menu and contact boxes. So I'm trying to get this to work with #skills first, and then I'll implement it on the other parts of the page. So far I'm unable to get the solutions for this to work (I tried modifying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287353/open-all-links-in-new-tabs-with-jquery)) .

I posted the whole thing as a snippet, instead of just the strictly relevant code in case I missed something obvious, like linking jQuery wrong or some random css flaw.

Any help and/or input is appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function {
  $('#skills a').click(function() {
    window.open($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
/********************************************
SPLOŠNO
********************************************/

body {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  line-height: 120%;
  margin: 0;
  background: url("../images/greyzz.png");
}
a {
  color: #94b7ec;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #0e2951;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/********************************************
HEADER
********************************************/

.header {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url("../images/header.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 40% 0%;
  padding: 7em 0 0.1em 1em;
  border-bottom: solid 0.5em #0e2951;
}
.header h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
.header h3 {
  color: #94b7ec;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: -1em;
}
.lang-icon-container {
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 78%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.lang-icon {
  width: 30%;
}
/********************************************
MENU
********************************************/

.menucontainer {
  margin-top: 1em;
  float: left;
  width: 33.3333%;
  text-align: center;
}
.menucontainer p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
}
.menucontainer p.icon {
  font-size: 8em;
}
/********************************************
SKILLS
********************************************/

#skills {
  margin: 12em auto 0 auto;
}
.skills-header {
  background-color: #0e2951;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.1em 1em;
}
.skills-header.p {
  margin: 0;
}
.skills-container {
  background-color: #3d7ddd;
  color: #eaf1fb;
  width: 100%;
}
.skills-container ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2em;
}
.skills-container li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.skills-container li.break {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.skills-container li.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4em;
}
.skills-container li a.profile-icon {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
/********************************************
PORTFOLIO
********************************************/

.portfolio-header {
  background-color: #0e2951;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.1em 0.5em;
}
.portfolio-header.p {
  margin: 0;
}
.portfolio-container {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
  background-color: red;
  background-color: #3d7ddd;
}
.portfolio-container ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1em;
}
.portfolio-container li {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
.portfolio-container li p {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #b1caf1;
  color: #0e2951;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.portfolio-image {
  max-width: 100%;
}
/********************************************
CONTACT
********************************************/

#contact {
  border-top: solid 0.5em #0e2951;
  border-bottom: solid 0.5em #0e2951;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-top: 1em;
}
.contact-icon-box {
  width: 32.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.contact-icon-link {
  width: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #3d7ddd;
  border-radius: 150px;
  font-size: 5em;
}
#contact p,
#contact #tablet-phone p {
  padding: 1em 2em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
#tablet-phone,
#facebook-tablet,
#email-tablet {
  display: none;
}
#tablet-phone p {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/********************************************
FOOTER
********************************************/

footer {
  text-align: center;
}
.back-to-top {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
.back-to-top p {
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: #3d7ddd;
  border-radius: 150px;
  width: 2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
}
.copyright {
  margin: 2em 0;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
/********************************************
TABLET ADJUSTMENTS
********************************************/

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /********************************************
 CONTACT ADJUSTMENTS
 ********************************************/
  #mobile-phone {
    display: none;
  }
  #tablet-phone,
  #facebook-tablet,
  #email-tablet {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #tablet-phone {
    color: #94b7ec;
  }
}
/********************************************
LAPTOP ADJUSTMENTS
********************************************/

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    margin: 0 5%;
  }
  /********************************************
 PORTFOLIO
 ********************************************/
  .portfolio-header {
    background-color: #0e2951;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.1em 0.5em;
  }
  .portfolio-header.p {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .portfolio-container {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
    background-color: red;
    background-color: #3d7ddd;
  }
  .portfolio-container ul {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .portfolio-container li {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 1em 4.8%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .portfolio-container li p {
    background-color: #b1caf1;
    color: #0e2951;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .portfolio-image {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
/********************************************
DESKTOP ADJUSTMENTS
********************************************/

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    margin: 0 15%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Miha Šušteršič</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500,700&amp;ssubset=latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ionicons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header" id="header">
      <div class="lang-icon-container">
        <a href="index_en.html">
          <img class="lang-icon" src="images/UnitedKingsom.png" alt="english flag">
        </a>
        <a href="index.html">
          <img class="lang-icon" src="images/Slovenia.png" alt="slovenian flag">
        </a>
      </div>
      <h2>Miha Šušteršič</h2>
      <h3>Web developer/designer</h3>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section id="menu">
    <a href="#skills">
      <div class="menucontainer">
        <p class="icon ion-code-working"></p>
        <p>Skills</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#porfolio">
      <div class="menucontainer">
        <p class="icon ion-document"></p>
        <p>Portfolio</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#contact">
      <div class="menucontainer">
        <p class="icon ion-ios-email"></p>
        <p>Contact</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </section>

  <section id="skills">
    <div class="skills-header">
      <p>Hello World! I can code:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="skills-container">
      <ul>
        <li>&lt; html5 &gt;</li>
        <li>{ css3 }</li>
        <li>javascript.js</li>
        <li class="break">$(jQuery)</li>
        <li class="break">&lt;%= rails 4 %&gt;</li>
        <li class="break">&lt; div class="bootstrap" &gt;</li>
        <li class="break">$ sudo apt-get update</li>
        <li class="inline">
          <a href="https://si.linkedin.com/pub/miha-šušteršič/b2/60/654" class="profile-icon ion-social-linkedin"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="inline">
          <a href="https://github.com/Shooshte" class="profile-icon ion-social-github"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="porfolio">
    <div class="portfolio-header">
      <p>Some of my recent work</p>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-container">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="http://zic.herokuapp.com/">
            <img class="portfolio-image" src="images/ZIC-screenshot.png" alt="ZIC Homepage">
          </a>
          <p>Renovated an old library Homepage.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://www.topdeckandwreck.com/grafiIJS/">
            <img class="portfolio-image" src="images/grafi-screenshot.jpg" alt="Javascript Interactive Graphs">
          </a>
          <p>Interactive JS Graphs made from MS excel tables.</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>

    <div id="contact">
      <div class="contact-icon-box">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/miha.sustersic.5">
          <div class="contact-icon-link ion-social-facebook">
          </div>
          <p id="facebook-tablet">Miha Šušteršič</p>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="contact-icon-box" id="mobile-phone">
        <a href="tel:+38631535919">
          <div class="contact-icon-link ion-ios-telephone">
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="contact-icon-box" id="tablet-phone">
        <div class="contact-icon-link ion-ios-telephone">
        </div>
        <p>+386 31535919</p>
      </div>

      <div class="contact-icon-box">
        <a href="mailto:sustersic_miha@hotmail.com">
          <div class="contact-icon-link ion-email">
          </div>
          <p id="email-tablet">sustersic_miha@hotmail.com</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <p>I am currently looking for design and/or development work. If interested, contact me using facebook or email. Please only use phone contact when urgent.</p>
    </div>

  </section>

  <footer>
    <a href="#header">
      <div class="back-to-top">
        <p class="ion-chevron-up"></p>
        Back to Top
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="copyright">
      &copy; Miha Šušteršič, 2015
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Good old target="_blank" won't do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to open link in new tab by script just use '_blank' parameter:

```
  $('#skills a').click(function() {
    window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank');
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: Found this anwser before, tried it and it didn't work. Turns out my jquery cdn link was broken, switched to google, used this code and now it works. Will accept solution when the timing restriction is over

Answer (score 1):

Just set the target attribute..

```
 $(document).ready(function {
      $('#skills a').attr('target', '_blank');
 });
```

Or just add that to the html, like

```
<a href="#skills" target="_blank">...
```